# How can i change the HTML <Table> colums heading in Vtiger CRM 1.5.0.?

Tags: php, mysql, vtiger

How can I change the HTML  columns heading in Vtiger CRM 1.5.0?

Suppose I have a HTML table and it has two headings columns `ID and First Name`, and I have to change the column heading `First Name to Person Name`. How can i do this in Vtiger CRM? 
I mean in which files do I have to make changes to make the column heading (First Name to Person Name).

Description
In list view there are may rows when I click on edit link that record opened in new window with its all values. There is a html table with two heading column ID, First Name. I need to change this First Name to Person name.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Modules/your_module_name/language/*.php -> Find "First Name" then change the label

If it doesnt work, Go to Modules/your_module_name.php -> Find "First Name" then change the label